# Segmentation fault in Java 3D on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, arm, raspberry-pi, java-3d

I'm trying to run a program using Java 3d on a Raspberry Pi and I'm having some problems with the native libraries.  I've found a version compiled for ARM on the debian website here

http://packages.debian.org/en/wheezy/armhf/libjava3d-jni/download

I've also tried the 'dfsg-9' version.

When I try and run the program the following output is printed:

```
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0xa6e5b9e2, pid=7251, tid=3057575024

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode linux-arm )
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libj3dcore-ogl.so+0x69e2]  Java_javax_media_j3d_NativePipeline_getAWT+0x11
```

I don't really have any experience debugging problems to do with native code and am hoping for some advice on how to proceed with ths problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you use the version 1.6 with JOGL 2? http://tinyurl.com/cf47kcb

Comment: I wasn't aware that Java 3D was back in development, I'll give it a look. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Java 3D was back in maintenance in 2012. It is still actively maintained but no new feature will be implemented. It still requires AWT, make sure that you use a JVM supporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry PI is based on an ARMv6 architecture processor. Debian armhf requires ARMv7 (or later). Hence an illegal instruction exception is exactly what I would expect.

Debian armel distribution works on the RPI.
However, if you are adding these packages to something like a raspian installation, that is unlikely to work, and you need to get your packages from a raspian repository.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting, thanks. I can't see an armel version of the library available anyway, but if I could get hold of the source should I in theory be able to compile it myself on the Pi?

Comment: Actually, scratch that there is a Raspbian package available. The code now throws an exception but it's progress :p Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace indicates that your program triggered a `SIGILL`

> SIGILL The SIGILL signal is sent to a process when it attempts to
>   execute an illegal, malformed, unknown, or privileged instruction.

Unless you wrote native code, this error is not your fault or doing.  Try upgrading to the latest JDK (`Java7 update 45`) to see if this fixes it.

You can also try running your Java process with the `-Xint` flag to prevent any code from being dynamically compiled.  Though not a long term solution, it may help identify where the error is happening.  In your trace, it doesn't appear to be crashing in dynamically compiled code.